# angular 6 ionic Let http put request to search id in limited data

Tags: angular, http, angular6, httprequest, put

Is it possible to instruct http put request to search id in limited data? The scenario is I have a table named 'cart' which contains a list of data users added to their cart. The table 'cart' has a relationship with another table 'user' and contains user_id as a column. Now when I make http put request I usually send 'cart_id' as a parameter and it works fine. But angular in the background would search 'cart_id' in all records including other users 'user_id'. So it unnecessarily traverses data. So is there any way I can tell angular to search 'cart_id' in only records that have a specific 'user_id'.

For example. Update data at 'cart_id' 10 where 'user_id' is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are using angular as a backend service and not as an SPA application.

What you need, is for your endpoint to accept more that 1 parameteres. You are using a put parameter so I'm also assuming that you want to update the `cart` resource of the `user` resourse.

This would take the following format `http://hostname/api/user/{userId}/cart/{cardId}`

If you are using express js then that would look like:

```
app.route('/api/user/:userId/cart/:cartId').put((req, res) => {
  req.params['userId'];
  req.params['cartId'];
  res.send(200, req.body)
})
```

Same principle applies for all rest APIS. Setup your resources and access them in a hierarchy that makes sense.